# Difference between http and https technique

Tags: asp.net

Does it need `Certificate/License/Registration` before launching the website using `https`?

I want to use the mentioned code in `Global.asax` file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] 
+   HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you will never reach it, as it will loop in the `Application_BeginRequest` over and over as you are redirecting all requests...

Maybe what you're after is redirecting if the request comes from a non secure connection (http), no?

for that, see if the request comes from such connection like:

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
  }
```

Secondly, the HTTPS protocol needs to be up and running or you will get a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error thrown.

In Visual Studio, you can easily **enable https** in the project properties

[image]

and you will get the untruest warning

[image]

As Visual Studio generated (on installation) a default self signed certificated.

In production environment you will need to:

- if it's an intranet application, just use the self-signed certificate
- on a internet application, you do need to buy an SSL certificates, now-days they re cheaper and cheaper...

---

*From your comments* I have some question myself now...

- Do you understand what HTTPS does to the connection between client computer and server?
- Do you really need a secure connection between the two?
- What kind of data are you trying to secure?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share a link over **Request comes from a non secure connection** ?

Comment: Web.Config will be fine in this context ? If so, will it be possible to share a code link over it ?

Comment: *share a link* sure, you will get that annoying warning in the browser saying that *some* data is not secure, but sure you can! `web.config` is just a place to set application settings, no need to change any of it to work in secure and nonsecure connections...

Comment: **Do you understand what HTTPS does to the connection between client computer and server?** No. **Do you really need a secure connection between the two?** Yes. **But** With best technique. **What kind of data are you trying to secure?** I have a query here. Can you tell exactly what issues can come if I use `http` ?

Comment: what kind of query? a SQL query?

Comment: I meant to said I had a question to ask. **Can you tell exactly what issues can come if I use http ?**

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use [secure HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) (using the HTTPS protocol) you say that the traffic between the browser and server is encrypted.

This means you need a certificate on the server so that the browser and server can decide on how to encrypt the traffic.

This has nothing to do with redirects and everything to do with your server setup.

Comment: When you said **traffic between the browser and server is encrypted.** Can you give some detailed link over it please ? Thanks you so much for the reply.

Comment: @Guest - Did you look at the link I provided?

Comment: Sorry. I will go through it first. Thanks.

Comment: My query is after reading the article. **HTTPs keep user communications and browsing history private**. So Browsing History is always private. As it is on individual machine. Right?

Comment: @Guest - Private means that the history is only known between the browser and server.